# imquantsize function in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, threshold

I'm new to Matlab and trying to take a tif and find and apply multiple thresholds.  I saved the tif using `I=imread('full_file_directory')` and used multithresh to find the threshold values.  However when I try to use `imquantize(image,threshold)` it keeps returning a totally white image (all ones).  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How many threshold values did you try to find and what were the values returned?

Comment: I tried to find three thresholds and received 60 122 192

Comment: Can you show your complete code (loading image, running `multithresh` and calling `imquantize`)? It's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: >>Image=imread('P:\1\Image_2788.tif');
>> thresh=multithresh(Image,3);
>> new=imquantize(Image,thresh);

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is not the use of `imquantize` itself, but how you're showing the results afterwards (to doublecheck, examine the maximum and minimum values of `new`).

By default, if you call `new=imquantize(Image,thresh);`, and `thresh` contains 3 values, the matrix `new` will contain the values 1 through 4 as described in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imquantize.html).  In addition, the output of `imquantize`, when thresholds are supplied but values are not, is of type double.

Therefore, if you try to show this image `new` using `imshow`, it will display an entirely white image, as by default it expects images of type double to have the range [0 1].

**Solution:** Use the `values` input in `imquantize` to define the output values - this should have the additional perk of keeping the output as the same type as your input.

For N number of thresholds you need N + 1 values, so for example try:

```
Image=imread('P:\1\Image_2788.tif');
thresh=multithresh(Image,3);
new=imquantize(Image,thresh, [0 thresh]);
```

This sets any pixels in the output image which are ≤ your first threshold value to 0 (black), values between the first and second thresholds to `thresh(1)`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying it from the min-max limit ?
You maybe are not displaying it correctly.
Use `imshow(new,[]);` to see your image.
You can see why we do it, here- 
[What does `imshow(someImage, [])` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280567/what-does-imshowsomeimage-do)