# Why imshow not work on some input whereas imagesc work properly?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

imshow does not work well with values (especially decimal), where as imagesc work seemlessly with same values.

Example:

```
     image = [0 0 0; 200.50 200 200; 128 128 128]; 
     figure;
     colormap gray;
     imshow(image);
     figure; 
     colormap gray;
     imagesc(image);
```

Comment: Why does it not work? I get a image with three different drak rectangles, each representing one pixel.

Comment: Have a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19280567/2778484).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to read the [documentation about `imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html), or type `help imshow` and pay attention to the following paragraph:

> If your grayscale image is single or double, the default display range
>   is [0 1]. If your image's data range is much larger or smaller than the default
>   display range, you may need to experiment with setting the display range to
>   see features in the image that would not be visible using the default
>   display range. For all grayscale images having integer types, the default
>   display range is [intmin(class(I)) intmax(class(I))]

In your attempt to use `imshow`, values greater than 1 are shown as white. It is not related to the fact that the values are decimal. Use:

```
imshow(image, []);
```

if you want the colormap to span the entire range of your image. Or in fact, just use `imagesc` that does it for you.

Comment: you can achieve the same by `imshow(image,[])`

Comment: @Adiel right, edited accordingly.